# Extending MySQLi giving me error

Tags: php, mysqli

I am trying to figure out how can I extend mysqli with my classes.

This is my db class;

```
class db {
    protected $_server  = "localhost";
    protected $_user    = "root";
    protected $_pwd     = "";
    protected $_db      = "test";
    protected $_charset = "utf8";

    function __construct(){
        $this->createConnection();
    }

    private function createConnection(){
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli($this->_server, $this->_user, $this->_pwd, $this->_db);
        $this->mysqli->query("SET NAMES ".$this->_charset);
        $this->mysqli->query("SET CHARACTER SET ".$this->_charset);
        if($this->mysqli->connect_error) {
            //die('Error ('.$this->mysqli->connect_errno.') '.$this->mysqli->connect_error());
            die();
        }

        //$this->mysqli->close();
    }

    public function mysqli_fetch_object($query){
        $query = $this->mysqli->query($query);
        return $query->fetch_object();
    }

}
```

and I want to extend this db class in this login class:

```
require_once("dbClass.php");
class login extends db {
    public function __construct(){

    }
    public function check_login($email, $password) {
        $email          = $this->mysqli->real_escape_string($email);
        $validateMail   = filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL);
        $password       = $password;
        $database_check = $this->mysqli_fetch_object("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = '$validateMail'");

    }
}
```

and I get these:

```
Notice: Undefined property: login::$mysqli

Fatal error: Call to a member function real_escape_string() on a non-object
```

Comment: technically you're not "extending" mysqli. you're just wrapping it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you override `__construct`, the original constructor won't run and won't create the connection.

Answer (score 2):

There is no point in extending login from db.
Instead of extending you have to use database class as a service in login class.

```
class login{
    public function __construct($db){
        $this->db = $db;
    }
    public function check_login($email, $password) {
         $stmt = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = ?");
         ...
    }
}
```

Also note that your way of running queries is wrong. You have to use prepared statements

Answer (score 1):

First, you use `$this->mysqli`, but there's no property `$mysqli` in the `db` class. Declare it as `protected`, since the extended class will need access to it:

```
protected $mysqli;
```

And second, you must call parent's constructor as other people said, otherwise it won't run.

But as a side note, I suggest you don't extend the `db` class as `login`. The best approach I found so far, is to have a db access class, instantiated as a singleton for your app. This way any class that needs it will ask for a singleton instance and use it.

The advantage is obvious: all your db access will occur thru a single instance, making your app much more efficient, because everything will be done thru a single database connection. The way you're doing, as soon as you construct a login instance, a new database connection will be established.

If you keep extending the `db` class to other classes, like users, products, and so on, new db connections will be created, wasting resources on your server.

Answer (score 0):

You should remove the constructor overload, or in your constructor method you should make a call to `parent::__construct`.  Without it, the parent's constructor is not fired.

```
class login extends db {
    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
    }
```